# How to determine the root directory of a project for config/rc files

Tags: node.js, configuration, rc

I'm writing a CLI tool in Node and I'd like it to be configurable by a config file when it's used by a consumers project. Pretty similar to how es-lint's `.eslintrc` or babel `.bablerc` works.

```
consumer-app
  node_modules
    my-cli-tool
      index.js ← my tool
  .configfile ← configuration file for the cli tool
  package.json
```

These files are usually placed at the root of the project and sometimes you can have multiple config files at different levels of the file tree.

```
consumer-app
  sub-directory
    .configfile ← another configuration file for this sub-dir
  node_modules
    my-cli-tool
      index.js ← my tool
  .configfile ← configuration file
  package.json
```

What's the overall architecture of building something similar? I can have my module look for its config file - but I'm having a hard time locating those config files or the root directory of a project because that's most likely where they're going to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem by looking the config file up the tree of a given `__dirname`.

This following method takes a filename and scans up the tree each directory the `__dirname` is part of until it finds the given file. This also makes it possible for each directory to have its own config file.

```
function getRootFile(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let lastFound = null;
    let lastScanned = __dirname;
    __dirname.split('/').slice(1).reverse().forEach(dir => {
      const parentPath = path.resolve(lastScanned, '../');
      if (fs.existsSync(path.join(parentPath, filename))) {
        lastFound = path.join(parentPath, filename);
      }
      lastScanned = parentPath;
    });
    resolve(lastFound);
  });
}

async function main() {
  const configPath = getRootFile('.myapprc')
}
```

This is only a proof-of-concept so it isn't perfect, but something to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.